# How to read user defined types from Oracle using cx_Oracle in Python

Tags: cx-oracle

This code works...
Its making a call to oracle function dbms_comparison.compare
With in/out/return parameters as such...

```
DBMS_COMPARISON.COMPARE(
  comparison_name  IN   VARCHAR2,
  scan_info        OUT  COMPARISON_TYPE,
  min_value        IN   VARCHAR2   DEFAULT NULL,
  max_value        IN   VARCHAR2   DEFAULT NULL,
RETURN BOOLEAN
```

The call succeeds

```
  try:
      with cx_Oracle.connect(
              config.username,
              config.password,
              config.dsn,
              encoding=config.encoding) as connection:
          with connection.cursor() as cursor:
              comparison_type = connection.gettype( "DBMS_COMPARISON.COMPARISON_TYPE")
              scan_info = cursor.var(comparison_type)

              result = cursor.callfunc("dbms_comparison.compare", bool, [comparison_name, scan_info, None, None, True])
  except cx_Oracle.Error as error:
      print(error)
```

I am doing this below to tell cx_oracle about the shape of the out parameter scan_info

```
          comparison_type = connection.gettype( "DBMS_COMPARISON.COMPARISON_TYPE")
          scan_info = cursor.var(comparison_type)
```

scan_info has a value, and all looks good, see image below.

BUT, how do I retrieve the individual values from the scan_info return value shapes as...

```
          TYPE COMPARISON_TYPE IS RECORD(
            scan_id            NUMBER,
            loc_rows_merged    NUMBER,
            rmt_rows_merged    NUMBER,
            loc_rows_deleted   NUMBER,
           rmt_rows_deleted   NUMBER)
```

I searched for too long for this and could not find the answer.
Strange surely this is run of the mill with database function taking/returning user defined types?!

You'd expect the result to be accessed as:

```
scan_info.scan_id
scan_info.loc_rows_merged
```

But apparently its not as simple as that and the Oracle docs do not mention how to do this.
So, if you my friend has done something similar before, please enlighten me.

[image]

Comment: I'd expect the results to be available with x.SCAN_ID etc - the case matters.  One example to review is https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/main/samples/tutorial/solutions/bind_sdo.py

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the attributes you need to do this:

```py
scan_info_inst = scan_info.getvalue()
print("Scan ID:", scan_info_inst.SCAN_ID)
```

As Chris mentioned, the case matters!